# Problema com alterações de temporarios visual studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, team-foundation-server

Ola,

Estou migrando do TFS para o GIT, fiz a importação no proprio azure de um novo repositório dando como origem o meu projeto no TFS...

Fez a importação, abri o projeto no visual studio, porém aparece essas alterações...

Peguei um gitignore na net:
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

Tentei utilizar o comando sugerido neste post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15345709/10647645, tambem nao funcionou...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguem ja passou por isso, ou sabe como resolver?

Comment: Você já fez o commit do .gitignore no repositório?

Comment: Sim, eu resolvi fazendo em todos os pcs que estao no mesmo projeto este comando git rm --cached *.extensao... Mas ainda gostaria de saber se ha um jeito definitivo, pq fiz esse procedimento ontem, quando abri hoje, tinha menos q ontem mais tinha alguns de novo...

Comment: Que na realidade o jeito definitivo seria com o gitignore ne....

Comment: Acho que nem é questão de "jeito definitivo", é o único... o que você fez na verdade foi retirar da área de commit...
Algum motivo de você não ter colocado o arquivo .gitignore?